# EXCEL - Find if value exists in column B in the range of a value in column A

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a list of companies with certain products. Now I want to find out if one company has a certain product or not. Example, I want to find out which company had Product C and return a one on all cells:

Column 1
Company A
Company A
Company A
Company A
Company B
Company B

Column 2
Product A
Product B
Product C
Product A
Product B

Column 3 (Result):
1
1
1
0
0

Comment: Result column should have 4 times 1 as `Product C` has `Company A` and `Company A` is repeated 4 times in Column A.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will require 2 additional columns. I'm assuming your first row is headers, and the range is from `A1:B6`. Data starts on Row 2. I'll give a few options on how to execute this though. Where I put `"Product C"` can also reference a cell. Whenever I'm using binary like this it's usually to filter datasets, so there might be a better alternative to what you want vs. what's below.

In Column C, `=if(B2="Product C",1,0)` or you can use `=--(B2="Product C")`

Sort by Column C in Descending Order, `=vlookup(A2,$A$2:$A$6,1,0)` copy and paste as values, but if you keep the formula and resort it will mess up.

If Product C would **only appear once for any given company** you can us `Sumifs` too. `=Sumifs($C$2:$C$6,$A$2:A$6$,A2)`

**If you have 365**, you can also use `Maxifs($C$2:$C$6,$A$2:A$6$,A2)`, which won't care how you sort the dataset.

Comment: Thank you mark for your quick response. However, If i type =vlookup(A2,$A$2:$A$6,1,0) it returns just the name same name. 

The file large file with lots of differen companies and lots of different products. I want to find out if company A has product A and C it must be identified as "AC" for example for all rows

Comment: Hi @Jannes123, it sounds like the question is a different scope than you originally mentioned. In your post you said to check for "Product C", but here you've mentioned you're looking for multiple products and trying to combine their suffixes them into single cells? Could you edit your question to better clarify the scope of your request?